# Excel Choosing Column based on filter criteria of other column

Tags: excel-formula

```
Name   Skill
Mike  Engineer
Salom  Doctor
Riku   Labour
Sindu  Engineer
```

We need to select who all are engineers or doctors

Comment: I have to do this using formula

Answer (score 2):

Use [**`COUNT`**](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNT-function-a59cd7fc-b623-4d93-87a4-d23bf411294c) and [**`SEARCH`**](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SEARCH-SEARCHB-functions-9ab04538-0e55-4719-a72e-b6f54513b495). If `D2` is the cell you're searching in then:

```
=COUNT(SEARCH({"Doctor","Engineer"},D2))
```

Drag this formula downwards to apply to all rows.

[image: result]

---

**Edit:** As you now mentioned that you want to print the names in the `Result` column, combine the above formula with [**`IF`**](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IF-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2) like this:

```
=IF(COUNT(SEARCH({"Doctor","Engineer"},D2)),C2,"")
```

where `D2` is the cell that you're searching in and `C2` is the cell that you want in the result cell if `Doctor` or `Engineer` exists in the cell `D2`. Dragging the formula downwards to apply to all rows gives:

[image: result2]

Comment: Thanks but I want to print name in result

Comment: Wow..thanks but my requirement here is  row wise like

Comment: Engineer or Doc    Name1   Name2     Name3

Comment: Got it? Are you able to get my question?

Comment: Suppose I tell you have to write the coulmn E in single row. How you gonna do it then?

Comment: Can't you modify that accordingly? I can't test at the moment

Comment: No we cant actually do that because here you just dragged you got the columns automatically but in rows you dont have that option

Comment: Plus here we are getting space in between which is not correct

Comment: it should be like when Engineer is there all  name should come in a single row

Comment: Please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)!

Answer (score 0):

> *You should accept @SardarUsama's solution as answer because it answers your actual question. If your requirement changes/extends or you were not able to put your question correctly to others then it is advisable that you accept the provided solution and then ask new question instead of making people change answer number of times.*

Now, coming to your question (as per comment shared between you and @SardarUsama's) following might be helpful.

Enter the following formula in `Cell C2`

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$10, SMALL(IF(($B$2:$B$10="Engineer")+($B$2:$B$10="Doctor"), ROW($A$2:$A$10)-1, ""), COLUMN(B$1)-COLUMN($A$1))),"")
```

This is an array formula so commit it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Or else you can use another array formula

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$10, SMALL(IF($B$2:$B$10={"Engineer","Doctor"}, ROW($A$2:$A$10)-1, ""), COLUMN(C$1)-COLUMN($B$1))),"")
```

Drag/Copy across as required. See image for reference.

[image]